# Unable to load angularJS view in .net core mvc

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

So I am having trouble loading my custom CreateBooking.html which only has this as a test

```
<div class="container">
<h2>AngularJS Test</h2></div>
```

My structure is like this

[image]

The main angular module

```
module Asda {
var app = angular.module("BookingApp", ["ngRoute"])
    .config(function ($routeProvider: ng.route.IRouteProvider, $locationProvider: ng.ILocationProvider) {
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

}

The controller

```
module Asda {
export class CreateBookingController {
    static $inject = ["$scope", "$http"];

    bookingData: IBookingViewModel;     

    constructor($scope, $http) {    
        this.bookingData.Action = "Test";
    }

    static routing($routeProvider) {            

        $routeProvider.when("/createbooking",
            {
                controller: "CreateBookingController",
                templateUrl: "/app/CreateBooking/CreateBooking.html",
                controllerAs: "ctr"                 
            });
    }
}

angular.module("BookingApp")
    .controller("CreateBookingController", CreateBookingController)
    .config(["$routeProvider", CreateBookingController.routing]);
```

};

As I am using .net core MVC I am catching the request and loading a generic cshtml view which has this inside

```
<div ng-view>
```

So angular should be able to load its view... however the html in CreateBooking.html is not rendered..

I have added the files in this order in my head section

```
<script src="~/js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/js/angular-route.min.js"></script>   
<!-- Main angular app module-->
<script src="~/App/BookingApp.js"></script>
<!-- Angular controllers-->
<script src="~/App/CreateBooking/CreateBookingController.js"></script>
```

angular and angular-route are both v1.7.9

I am at a loss.. :/

Comment: If I put an alert in the routing method on the CreateBookingController then it doesnt popup so that is concerning. There are also no script errors which doesn't help.

Comment: That shouldn't define a module twice, thats the way you wire up a controller to an angular module, I have seen it done that way in pluralsight videos and in real life apps. However I updated it to refer to the module var instead but still the same problem. Moving the routing to the main module doesnt make a different either, again I saw production apps that had the route in the controller.. :/

Comment: I don't see you binding your app anywhere in your html. <div ng-view> is not enough to get your app to run. Add somewhere ng-app="BookingApp" above the ng-view. Check [this](https://www.guru99.com/angularjs-first-program.html) out

Comment: Oh my god.. I forgot the ng-app="BookingApp" that has sorted it! lol.. damn.

Answer (score 0):

Dont forget to kickstart with ng-app!